# How to get all the tasks that are running currently

Tags: android, activity-manager

I want to get all the tasks that are running in android.I found getRunningTasks in ActivityManager but from android-5.0 the getRunningTasks may not give all the tasks (in my case it's give the home screen and my application).

In addition is it possible to find the task that the user is currently interacting with?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**Edit**: I am using the following piece of code.But it's giving me only one process (that's my app).Even if i open other apps it's not showing them.I am running this on One Plus2.

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getRunningApps();
            }
        }, 0, 1000);//put here time 1000 milliseconds=1 second
    }

    public void getRunningApps() {
        final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

        for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++)
        {
            Log.d("Executed app", "Application executed : " +recentTasks.get(i).pkgList[0]+ "\t\t ID: "+recentTasks.get(i).pid+"");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `getRunningAppProcesses`, which will return a list of `RunningAppProcessInfo` objects that will give you some data about each running app. One of the pieces of information you can retrieve about the app is its `importance`, which can have a value `IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND` which indicates that the process is the currently active application!

**Related Documentation:**

[getRunningAppProcesses](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses())

[RunningAppProcessInfo](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html)

[IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html#IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND)

If this helped you, feel free to press that arrow to the left :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not the owner of that task, Android won't give you its info.

Comment: But if you see voodoo app, they show their widget only in certain apps.So i thought this might be possible.But if there is any work around for such a problem please suggest me the way.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `code` Its works for me. Dont forgot to use `ListView` in your `Xml` File.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        String[] values = new String[procInfos.size()];
        final String packageName = "my.application.package";
        PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        for (int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++) {
            values[i] = procInfos.get(i).processName;
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe [**getRecentTasks**](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks%28int,%20int%29) and [**getRunningTask**](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29) were deprecated as of API 21. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, perhaps u should try [**getRunningAppProcess**](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29). which give u a similar result.

Comment: This is a verified solution?