# How can I get all the applications that are currently running on android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to get all running app on my android device. Maybe, need to use `PackageManager`? I have tried used to `PackageManager`, but I did not succeed, maybe, you have better decision?

Comment: All running app or all installed app ?

Answer (score 1):

Using below code you can get running application list

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can detect information about running process using `ActivityManager`.

I think you should check with these same questions here:

[How to get the list of running application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304685/how-to-get-the-list-of-running-applications)

[How to get all the tasks that are running currently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35812791/how-to-get-all-the-tasks-that-are-running-currently)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following thread. Your question has already been answered.

> ActivityManager has method getRunningTasks(int). ActivityManager seems
>   to be the solution you are searching for.

```
 final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
    {
        Log.d("Executed app", "Application executed : " +recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()+ "\t\t ID: "+recentTasks.get(i).id+"");         
    }
```

---

[Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091350/how-to-find-the-currently-running-applications-programatically-in-android)